# Gradually increasing the size of the output layer

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network, transfer-learning

Let's say I have a flattened image as a CNN output and I would like to recover it in a sequence of steps. I want to train the network to recover a 4x4 section at the center of the image at first (i.e., 16 output nodes) . In the second step, I would like to freeze the learned connections in the output layer, and add to them another 4x4 section (i.e., doubling th size of output last layer), and so on so forth until I have recovered the entire image.

The only possible way I could think of is throguh transfer learning, but I'm really not sure how that could be achieved in TensorFlow.

Answer (score 0):

One way is using concatenated sequence, you compared the different learning processes or add more input from the original image, or duplicated multiple tasks on the same inputs as you specified in the requirements.

Sample: "Priority" is primary and "Departure" is secondary less priority see [Multiple class input model](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/functional)

```
import os
from os.path import exists

import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_io as tfio

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
None
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
physical_devices = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
assert len(physical_devices) > 0, "Not enough GPU hardware devices available"
config = tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)
print(physical_devices)
print(config)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
Variables
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
PATH = os.path.join('F:\\datasets\\downloads\\Actors\\train\\Pikaploy', '*.tif')
PATH_2 = os.path.join('F:\\datasets\\downloads\\Actors\\train\\Candidt Kibt', '*.tif')
files = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(PATH)
files_2 = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(PATH_2)

list_file = []
list_file_actual = []
list_label = []
list_label_actual = [ 'Pikaploy', 'Pikaploy', 'Pikaploy', 'Pikaploy', 'Pikaploy', 'Candidt Kibt', 'Candidt Kibt', 'Candidt Kibt', 'Candidt Kibt', 'Candidt Kibt' ]
for file in files.take(5):
    image = tf.io.read_file( file )
    image = tfio.experimental.image.decode_tiff(image, index=0)
    list_file_actual.append(image)
    image = tf.image.resize(image, [32,32], method='nearest')
    list_file.append(image)
    list_label.append(1)
    
for file in files_2.take(5):
    image = tf.io.read_file( file )
    image = tfio.experimental.image.decode_tiff(image, index=0)
    list_file_actual.append(image)
    image = tf.image.resize(image, [32,32], method='nearest')
    list_file.append(image)
    list_label.append(9)
    
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
DataSet
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((tf.constant(tf.cast(list_file, dtype=tf.int64), shape=(10, 1, 32, 32, 4), dtype=tf.int64),tf.constant(list_label, shape=(10, 1, 1), dtype=tf.int64)))

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Model Initialize
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
first_input = tf.keras.Input(shape=( 32, 32, 4 ), name="first input" )
second_input = tf.keras.Input(shape=( 32, 32, 4 ), name="second input" )

priority_pred = tf.keras.layers.Normalization(mean=3., variance=2.)(first_input)
priority_pred = tf.keras.layers.Normalization(mean=4., variance=6.)(priority_pred)
priority_pred = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu')(priority_pred)
priority_pred = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(priority_pred)
priority_pred = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(priority_pred)
priority_pred = tf.keras.layers.Reshape((128, 225))(priority_pred)
priority_pred = tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(96, return_sequences=True, return_state=False))(priority_pred)
priority_pred = tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(96))(priority_pred)
priority_pred = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(priority_pred)
priority_pred = tf.keras.layers.Dense(192, activation='relu')(priority_pred)
priority_pred = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, name="priority")(priority_pred)


department_pred = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu')(second_input)
department_pred = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(department_pred)
department_pred = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(department_pred)
department_pred = tf.keras.layers.Reshape((128, 225))(department_pred)
department_pred = tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(96, return_sequences=True, return_state=False))(department_pred)
department_pred = tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(96))(department_pred)
department_pred = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(department_pred)
department_pred = tf.keras.layers.Dense(192, activation='relu')(department_pred)
department_pred = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, name="department")(department_pred)


# Instantiate an end-to-end model predicting both priority and department
model = tf.keras.Model(
    inputs=[first_input, second_input],
    outputs=[priority_pred, department_pred],
)

model.summary()

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Optimizer
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Nadam(
    learning_rate=0.00001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-07,
    name='Nadam'
)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Loss Fn
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""                               
lossfn = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(
    from_logits=False,
    reduction=tf.keras.losses.Reduction.AUTO,
    name='sparse_categorical_crossentropy'
)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Model Summary
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,  loss={
                                            "priority": tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
                                            "department": tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
                                        },
                                    loss_weights={"priority": 1.0, "department": 0.2},
                                    metrics=['accuracy'])

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Training
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""

priority_targets = tf.constant(list_label, shape=(10, 1, 1), dtype=tf.int64)
dept_targets = tf.constant(list_label, shape=(10, 1, 1), dtype=tf.int64)
                        
history = model.fit( {"first input": tf.constant(tf.cast(list_file, dtype=tf.int64), shape=(10, 32, 32, 4), dtype=tf.int64), 
                        "second input": tf.constant(tf.cast(list_file, dtype=tf.int64), shape=(10, 32, 32, 4), dtype=tf.int64)},
                        
                     {"priority": priority_targets, "department": dept_targets},

                        batch_size=100, epochs=50 )
```

Output: Matrices need to custom to display the correct value, model is working and using logicals shape is true.

```
Epoch 49/50
1/1 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0000e+00 - priority_loss: 0.0000e+00 - department_loss: 0.0000e1/1 [==============================] - 0s 54ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - priority_loss: 0.0000e+00 - department_loss: 0.0000e+00 - priority_accuracy: 0.5000 - department_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 50/50
1/1 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0000e+00 - priority_loss: 0.0000e+00 - department_loss: 0.0000e1/1 [==============================] - 0s 54ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - priority_loss: 0.0000e+00 - department_loss: 0.0000e+00 - priority_accuracy: 0.5000 - department_accuracy: 0.5000
```

Comment: Thanks Jirayu for taking the time to type up this post, but I'm not sure how this solves my problem. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: First, for the image training process channels presents data that may duplicate some information between channels, imagine you had image segmentation that presents in red and yellow colors as wall or skins ( we not talking about shade but a bit of blue when the image process ) - we call this colors channels differentiate that is why they use greys color scales.
> Suppose to retraining all when networks change in the input but concatenate models or knowledge transfer or image channels transform RGBY -> RGB 
> Sample YOLO netowkrs must be concatenated model channels independency.